# at what stage of database query should i return the results to be able to use them as a fetch response

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, fetch

I am running a query on mysql database using prepared statements. I am able to make a successful query and i am returning the results. I would want to use this returned results and pass them to a page that is providing back end response to a javascript fetch request.
when i post data  and try to get a response i am not getting what i expect.

I expect to get an object or an array so that i can parse it and render a html page using javascript.
The response i am getting is this one below.

```
{current_field: null, field_count: null, lengths: null, num_rows: null, type: null}
current_field: null
field_count: null
lengths: null
num_rows: null
type: null
__proto__: Object
```

My php code that is generating the results is this one.

```
if($this->result->num_rows > 0){
return ($this->result);//returs results before using while loop for convinience of execution.
}else{
return ("no results to show");
}
```

I am sending the response to fetch request using 
    json_encode(results);

This is the fetch request i am using to send and receive request.

```
async receiveResponse (){
try{
const response = await fetch(this.url,{
method:this.method,
body:this.form 

})
const result = await this.responseType === 'text'? await response.text():await 
response.json();//allow send text and json
console.log(result);
}catch(e){

console.log(e);
}
}
```

I am using the results before doing the while loop in php-mysql and am not sure if this is the right thing to do.

Answer (score -2):

I have noticed that i should not attempt to return the results before running result->fetch_assoc() function.

thanks .